# matplot pandas plotting multiple y values on the same column

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, jupyter

Trying to plot using matplot but lines based on the value of a non x , y  column.

For example this is my DF:

```
code    reqs    value
AGB 253319  57010.16528
ABC 242292  35660.58176
DCC 240440  36587.45336
CHB 172441  57825.83052
DEF 148357  34129.71166
```

Which yields this plot df.plot(x='reqs',y='value',figsize=(8,4)) :

[image: plot without codes]

What I'm looking to do is have a plot with multiple lines one line for each of the codes. Right now its just doing 1 line and ignoring the code column.

I tried searching for an answer but each one is asking for multiple y's I dont have multiple y's I have the same y but with different focuses 
(surely i'm using the wrong terms to describe what I'm trying to do hopefully this example and image makes sense)

The result should look something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I worked out how to do exactly ^ if anyone is curious:

```
plt_df = df
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for key,grp in plt_df.groupby(['code']):
    ax = grp.plot(ax=ax, kind ='line',x='reqs',y='value',label=key,figsize=(20,4),title = "someTitle")

plt.show()
```